# Certain type of place in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using cord and ionic to create an application. I have to display a map, which already ok. But the map I wanted to display only a particular establishment, for example, map the cops or doctors.

My actually code:

```js
var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
var myOptions = '';

$cordovaGeolocation
.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
.then(function (position) {
  var getLat  = position.coords.latitude
  var getLong = position.coords.longitude
  myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(getLat, getLong),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  console.log(getLat);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}, function(err) {
  // error
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is.  Can you add more description, and perhaps give an example of what is wrong / unexpected from your code?

Comment: Hi, I need to list on the map only hospitals that region, for example!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ***[Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en)*** in order to get the establishment of your choice. Take a look at the list of the [types supported in Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

See the sample code:

```
 $(function () {
                var input = document.getElementById('location');
                var options = {                    
                    types: ['doctor']
                };
```